# Flask RESTful API : PUT request on multiple resources

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, flask, flask-restful

I'm working on an API using Flask-RESTful to handle "shares". Currently I have several methods (`GET`, `POST`, `PUT` and `DELETE`) and everything works perfectly. Today I can update the backup (via `PUT` method) of a single share by reaching `/api/v1/shares/{id}` (where id is the id of the share) and sending the `backup` argument in the body.

Here a snippet of my resource file called shares.py:

```
class ShareList(Resource):
    def __init__(self):
        self.reqparse = reqparse.RequestParser()
        self.reqparse.add_argument(
            'name',
            required=True,
            help='No name provided',
            location=['form', 'json']
        )
        self.reqparse.add_argument(
            'backup',
            required=True,
            help='No backup class provided',
            location=['form', 'json']
        )
        super().__init__()

    def get(self):
        blablabla

    def post(self):
        blablabla

class Share(Resource):
    def __init__(self):
    self.reqparse = reqparse.RequestParser()
    self.reqparse.add_argument(
        'backup',
        required=True,
        location=['form', 'json']
    )
    super().__init__()

def get(self, id):
    blablabla

def put(self, id):
    blablabla

def delete(self, id):
    blablabla

shares_api = Blueprint('resources.shares', __name__)
api = Api(shares_api)
api.add_resource(
    ShareList,
    '/shares',
    endpoint='share_list'
)
api.add_resource(
    Share,
    '/shares/<string:id>',
    endpoint='share'
)
```

Now, I would try to update multiple resources. The best will be to send my `PUT` request to `/api/v1/shares` including this body:

```
{
    "id1" : {"backup": "Gold"},
    "id2" : {"backup": "No backup"}
}
```

But I don't know how I can handle this case. I'm not sure also if RequestParser would be appropriate for this new case. Can you help me?

Comment: Any idea from anybody?